# With pam_script, how do I pass PAM_AUTHTOK and PAM_USER in all cases?

Tags: pam

I need to run a script whenever a user enters a password; the script should be able to reject that password, but shouldn't be sufficient.

I placed the script in `/etc/pamunlockscript/pam_script_auth` and added the following line at the end of `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`:

`auth required pam_script.so dir=/etc/pamunlockscript`.

According to `man 7 pam-script`,

```
All  the  scripts  will be passed several environment variables:
PAM_USER,  PAM_RUSER,   PAM_RHOST,   PAM_SERVICE,   PAM_AUTHTOK,
PAM_TTY,   and  PAM_TYPE  referring  to  the  module-type.
```

My test script is

```
#!/bin/sh
echo script: $PAM_AUTHTOK $PAM_USER
```

I expect every program that uses `pam` to echo `script: (my password) mic` whenever it verifies my password.

This works for the programs `login` and `i3lock`, but the script echoes `script:` for `sudo`.

Comment: Please provide at least the relevant part of your script.

Comment: The script is simply `echo $PAM_USER $PAM_AUTHTOK`.

Comment: Then where are you "attempting sudo"? Where do they get unset? Where's the problem if "your script prints the environment variables"?

Comment: I have clarified the question (I hope).

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your problem: everything works just fine when I try it on my machine. Could you provide the contents of your `/etc/sudoers` and `/etc/pam.d/sudo` files? Make sure there is no sensitive information in them before posting.

Comment: Got similar problem, please post any findings on the matter.

Comment: It looks like I gave up on the issue, since I didn't actually need `PAM_USER` in case of `sudo`.